# Can't mount 2nd HD SFS

Tags: 12.04, mount

I'm trying to mount a 1TB Western digital hd that was appearing fine yesterday before I reinstalled ubuntu 12.04. I  used to have a dual boot windows 7/ubuntu 12.04, and my 1TB drive would show up fine from either OS. Today, I wiped my boot drive in order to use it all for Ubuntu 12.04, i.e., remove windows 7, and now I'm trying to mount the 1TB drive to /media on my new installation without much success.

Here is the `fdisk` output for the device I'm trying to mount:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x6f25ce66

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63  1953523119   976761528+  42  SFS
```

I tried running `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media`, I get:
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

If I try to run `sudo mount -t sfs /dev/sdb /media`, I get:
mount: unkown filesystem type 'sfs'

I also tried mounting as `ntfs`, `ntfs-3g`, and a few other types, but of course it says 'device doesn't seem to have a valid ntfs' etc.

How can I mount this HD?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I know this was a while back but for some reason no one has made this information easily available so here is the answer:

It's very very simple.

Run `sudo apt-get install ldmtool` then make sure your drive is actually there by checking with `sudo fdisk -l` and once you have ldmtool downloaded, try to see if the harddrive is recognized by running `sudo ldmtool scan`. The print out should be a json like string with the device id. Finish by writing `sudo ldmtool create all`. DONE. You can now go to your /media folder and see all your mounted drives along with the newly mounted SFS partition!