# Mounting an SFS partition drive

Tags: partitioning, mount

Simply put: I have a secondary harddrive formatted in SFS for some reason so Ubuntu 13.10 can't see it. It used to be my Windows backup which is why it always worked fine. Now I no longer have Windows so I can't access the files. Does anyone know of a way to at least open it and transfer files out to another drive? I can format it afterwards but getting the information out first is of utmost importance.

Answer (score 8):

Found my own answer and answered [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231639/cant-mount-2nd-hd-sfs/412254#412254)

It's very very simple.

Run `sudo apt-get install ldmtool` then make sure your drive is actually there by checking with `sudo fdisk -l` and once you have ldmtool downloaded, try to see if the harddrive is recognized by running `sudo ldmtool scan`. The print out should be a json like string with the device id. Finish by writing `sudo ldmtool create all`. DONE. You can now go to your /media folder and see all your mounted drives along with the newly mounted SFS partition!

Comment: This worked for me. Want to add that `lsblk` can be used to see which devices are used after `ldmtool create all`. And the device itself can be accessed through for example `/dev/mapper/ldm_vol_NODE3-Dg0_Volume1` (where the `NODE3` part is the hostname).