Unable to reinstall Ubuntu after initial installation due to boot issues
I have known about Ubuntu since 2010, but today I officially want to switch to it because I am fed up with Windows products. I tried to install Ubuntu while still using Windows 10. I used it last night, and everything was OK. Since I installed quite a few applications and only allocated 15GB initially during the installation for Ubuntu, I faced an issue. When I booted it up again, it failed. I tried various ways, but I haven't succeeded until now.
I tried again, but the notification during booting is still the same.

I tried to remove the Ubuntu partition from Windows 10, but it didn't work either. I attempted to reinstall Ubuntu, but I still couldn't, as shown in the image in image 1. Finally, I tried trial and error, but it still didn't work.
Logically, I want to remove Ubuntu from the boot system, but I haven't been able to.

I tried to delete it so I can reinstall Ubuntu on my laptop, but it didn't work.

You did not allow enough for the Ubuntu OS in the first place. All docs tell you at least 25 gig for the OS and since many apps today use snaps that should be 50 gig. You do not uninstall an OS you write over it. You need to re-partition the hard drive and allow the 50 gig and then reinstall the Ubuntu OS. Do not to forget to back up any Windows data before starting. You also did not say in your question what version of Ubuntu you are trying to use.

Hi @David thank you for your help. Not really sure about your assistance as I am newbie and purpose to use ubuntu is to learn coding from 0 as I know nothing about it. So meaning you wanna say that I need to add a new partition which later can be used for ubuntu? Btw I use Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, as I just downloaded it last night.

Official How To Install Ubuntu doc. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview How was it that you installed it without a partition? Your question must be lacking a lot of details.

Hi @David , thanks for the link shared. The thing now is I want to remove Ubuntu from my laptop as shown in picture 2. So I can re-install the new one after removing it. Do you know anything to remove the OS from my laptop?

I already answered that you do not remove an OS you copy over it or delete the partition if not installing it again.

Warning: Be careful if you use Windows to configure partitions. It may well convert your disk to use a dynamic partition 'SFS' which is then somewhat difficult to confgure (convert back) without special Window tools and/or loss of data.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/412248/mounting-an-sfs-partition-drive https://askubuntu.com/questions/412248/mounting-an-sfs-partition-drive

You do not "remove" or "uninstall" a computer operating system.
You overwrite it with the new OS.
If you wish to replace your Windows + Ubuntu dual-boot setup with a single all-Ubuntu install, the simplest way is to backup all your data to some other media, then boot the LiveUSB Ubuntu Installer, and just follow the prompts.
