Dual boot is broken after upgrading to WIndows 11
I had Ubuntu installed (though I’m not sure which version) alongside Windows 10 in a dual boot setup, and everything was working fine. After upgrading to Windows 11, my GRUB bootloader broke. Now, when I boot up, I get the standard "Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported" message. If I exit, Ubuntu doesn't load, and I no longer have access to it.
I tried using a Disk-Repair (Boot-Repair???) live USB and followed the recommended steps to fix the issue, but nothing changed. Next I attempted to manually reinstall GRUB, but I failed to mount the primary partition to /mnt, which all the guides require. Since I can't save output from a Ubuntu live USB bash session, I’m attaching a screenshot of my disk partitions taken from Windows.
As you can see, I have UEFI.
Partition 5 is the Linux swap, and partitions 6 and 7 are the Ubuntu partitions (in fdisk -l they appear as /dev/sda5, /dev/sda6, and /dev/sda7). I tried mounting /dev/sda6 and /dev/sda7 to /mnt (each of them separately, but it failed, saying those aren't standard NTFS partitions (or something like that).
Partition 1 (/dev/sda1) is my boot partition, which should be eventually mounted to /mnt/boot/efi, but since I couldn't mount /mnt, this also failed.


It is not clear to me if you still have linux installed. Use a Ubuntu installer boot to check the disk partiitons sda5 & sda6 are still formatted to ext4 and data is still present (gparted?) then use the following link to re-install grub https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition

sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt  fails with the error that this isn't NTFS or something like that.
I've boot with Boot-Repair live USB and tried to reinstall grup but I get an error when I try to mount.

https://ibb.co/Kw3gL2s
Here’s what GParted displays. Do you think my Linux installation is corrupted

Windows sometimes does not update backup gpt table. Does this show anything more? sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda or does testdisk see partitions correctly? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Menu_Analyse  If partitions are seen as ext4, you can run e2fsck, but if not seen as ext4, it will not work.

It doesn't look good. I can't really see what has happened here? It looks a bit like WIN11 has changed the status of the disk in some way. what does 'sudo fdisk -l' show? I do wonder if it has converted it to SFS format. Also it possibly has been converted from MBR to GPT. It looks currently the latter. To attempt to mount a SFS partition see  https://askubuntu.com/questions/412248/mounting-an-sfs-partition-drive. You could also try recovery tools. See https://superuser.com/questions/274615/accidentally-reformatted-a-ext4-drive-to-ntfs-lost-all-data-what-are-my-option.
